# i am not able to remove grayscale via jquery

Tags: jquery, css, grayscale

my css code

```
.content-img  {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
       -o-transition: all 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
          transition: all 1s ease;
         -webkit-filter:grayscale(100%); 
}
```

my jquery

```
 $('.content-img').hover(function () {
        $(this).css('-webkit-filter', 'grayscale(0)');
    });
```

I just wanted to write jQuery. it doesnt work.

Comment: I think you need to make it more specific..

Comment: It works fine here - http://jsfiddle.net/YgdC3/ (In Chrome)

Comment: in fact it works when you move the mouse over the img, but moving out won't change it back, try this http://jsfiddle.net/V3Wcw/1/ , note that you use the `hover()` in the wrong way.

Comment: Why not use CSS itself: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/pNhLk/

Comment: @NickR: this is the way you do it: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/YgdC3/1/

Comment: @abhitalks Yes it is, you can either bind 1 or 2 handlers (1 for mouse in and one for mouse out) There was nothing mentioned that it should return to its original state.

Comment: @NickR: *".. nothing mentioned that it should return.."*: Fair enough! Can't agree more on that one! `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to use jQuery at all?

You can use this:

```
.content-img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
            filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

Here, I made you this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DhA6p/) using css only, with `:hover` selector.

But be careful, `filter` has limited support, look at [filter article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility).